# Change table structure with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a site with no access to the existing HTML , and i need to use jQuery to change the structure of the tables.

Here is the existing HTML table

```
<table id="MyTable">
 <caption></caption>
  <tbody>         <!--remove the tbody here and add thead-->
   <tr>           <!--remove this tr-->
    <th></th>        
    <th></th>        
    <th></th>  
   </tr>          <!--remove this tr and add a closing thead-->
                  <!--add opening tbody here -->
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to make the table layout look like this

```
<table id="MyTable">
 <caption></caption>
  <thead>        
    <th></th>        
    <th></th>        
    <th></th>   
  </thead>   
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So i need to wrap the th with thead , remove the tr also wrapping them
then move the tbody below the th and newly added thead. Is this possible ?

Comment: have you tried any thing ?

Comment: "*Is this possible?*" – yes. Where did you get stuck? And there has to be a `<tr>` surrounding the `<th>` elements, otherwise you'll have invalid HTML and then browser will try to repair the broken HTML when it builds the DOM, which will unpredictably change the underlying structure, causing both JavaScript/jQuery *and* CSS problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.before()`:

```js
var thead = $('<thead>', {   // creates a thead 
       html:$('#MyTable tbody tr').eq(0)  // <----puts the first tr of tbody
    });

    $('#MyTable tbody').before(thead)
    //$('#MyTable thead').find('th').unwrap(); // <-----use this to remove the tr but not needed.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="MyTable" border='1' width='90%'>
 <caption>caption here</caption>
  <tbody>         <!--remove the tbody here and add thead-->
   <tr>           <!--remove this tr-->
    <th>a</th>        
    <th>b</th>        
    <th>c</th>  
   </tr>          <!--remove this tr and add a closing thead-->
                  <!--add opening tbody here -->
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I suppose you need to have `tr` in the `thead` element.

Comment: ty Jai , that is perfect

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to add `th` element

```
$("#MyTable").find('tbody tr:first').append("<th>TH4</th>");
```

Rest of the code from Jai ( Best answer )

```
var thead = $('<thead>', {   // creates a thead 
   html:$('#MyTable tbody tr').eq(0)  // <----puts the first tr of tbody
});

$('#MyTable tbody').before(thead)
```